# unable to remove first character from search in input react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, debouncing

I have made a search field with debouncing. Everything works fine but when I try to empty the search field with backspace it continuously re-show all characters and does not remove them(the first character is always there).

you can see it in the attached gif

[image: Search field]

**my parent component**

```
  class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
        this.queryParam = {
                keyword: ''
             }
   
  keywordSearch = value => {
     const {
       history: { push },
       match: { url },
       location: { search },
       } = this.props;

    queryParams = {...queryParams, keyword: value, };

    push(`${url}?${queryString})
   };
   
   render() {
        <SearchComponent
            value={this.queryParams.keyword}
            onUpdate={this.keywordSearch}
         />
     }
  }
```

**my search field component**

```
   const SearchComponent = ({ value, onUpdate }) => {
    const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(value);

    const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
       debounceFunc(() => {
            onUpdate(value);
         }, 300);
         setFieldValue(value);
        };

   return (
      <Input
      value={fieldValue || value}
      disableUnderline
      onChange={handleChange}
      className={classes.root}
      placeholder='Search'
      startAdornment={
         <InputAdornment position="start">
           <Search className={classes.icon} fontSize="small" />
         </InputAdornment>
        }
     />
  }
```

**here is my custom debounce component**

```
  export const debounceFunction = () => {
    let timeOut = null;
    return (callBack, wait) => {
    if (timeOut) clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        callBack();
     }, wait);
    };
   };
  export const debounceFunc = debounceFunction();
```

the problem is in this debounce function. can anyone help me in this regard? why it isn't removing the first character?
Thanks

Comment: the problem seems to be in the `// value update function` and in the fact that you are calling `setFieldValue` outside of `debounceFunc` so you probably have 2 ways how the value is updated and those 2 ways fight each other

Comment: this search field is a child component and  update function from parent component which is handling value and sending back to backend @Aprillion

Comment: the code you listed here does not reproduce the problem => please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: just updated my question please have a look at it @Aprillion

Comment: Just feedback: I'm used to seeing a debounce look more like this... `let dbncd = debounce(fn, delay); ... onchange = dbncd;` so that, for instance, `fn` would receive, say, the `Event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is `<Input value={fieldValue || value}`
=> use just the local state:
`<Input value={fieldValue}` to change the visible value immediatelly.

Second problem is `this.queryParams.keyword` being an instance property, not a React State
=> use `this.state....` and `this.setState(...)` (or Hooks) to update debounced state in the parent

Answer (score -1):

I have changed debounceFunction parameter and the way to use it. Can you give it a try

```
    const SearchComponent = ({ value, onUpdate }) => {
        const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(value);
        
const debouncedUpdate = debounceFunction(onUpdate, 300);

        const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
           debouncedUpdate(value);
            setFieldValue(value);
           };
    
       return (
          <Input
          value={fieldValue || value}
          disableUnderline
          onChange={handleChange}
          className={classes.root}
          placeholder='Search'
          startAdornment={
             <InputAdornment position="start">
               <Search className={classes.icon} fontSize="small" />
             </InputAdornment>
            }
         />
      } 
    
      
    
    export const debounceFunction = (callBack, wait) => {
        let timeOut = null;
        return () => {
        if (timeOut) clearTimeout(timeOut);
        timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            callBack();
         }, wait);
        };
       };
      export const debounceFunc = debounceFunction();
```

Comment: your `debounceFunction` expects 2 parameters and you call it with none

Comment: @Aprillion I have called it by passing 2 parameters -> debounceFunc(onUpdate, 300);
Infact that's what I changed :)

Comment: getting error debouncedUpdate is not a function and if i just change the debounceFunction is give callback is not a function.
can you please look at this

Comment: yes, your `debounceFunc` takes 0 arguments and you called it with 2.. that's a second problem in your code

Comment: @UsmanSaleem changed 
const debouncedUpdate = debounceFunc(onUpdate, 300);
to
const debouncedUpdate = debounceFunction(onUpdate, 300);

My bad it was a typo. Can you check it now :)

Comment: @Aprillion this is the definition of debounceFunction
export const debounceFunction = (callBack, wait) => {...} 
which expects 2 parameters

Comment: @TauseefAhmad you called `debounceFunction` until you edited your answer. after the edit, you call `debounceFunction` directly, without the closure around variable `timeOut`, so you will never be able to cancel the setTimeout